# pywin32: save file as xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I'm trying to use pywin32 to convert an xls file to an xlsx file. This is how I went about it:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlApp.Visible = 1
xlApp.Workbooks.Open('old_file.xls') # An xls file.
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('new_file.xlsx', FileFormat=50, ConflictResolution=2) # 50=xlsx, 2=overwrite
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```

I got the 50 value from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). However, when I try to run this, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlapp_test.py", line 10, in <module>
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('new_file.xlsx', FileFormat=50, ConflictResolution=2) # 50=xlsx, 2=overwrite
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 7, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u'This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.', u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

So  I guess 50 doesn't work. How do I save a file as an xlsx with pywin32?

Comment: You might be able to look through the `xlwt` source and see if that helps answer how to convert it.

Comment: The files I'm trying to convert are pretty complex, with a lot of merged cells and different cell formats and stuff like that. I could theoretically use `xlrd` and `xlwt`, but everything I've seen on them tells me that while moving the cell contents is easy, moving all the formatting is harder.

Comment: 51 was the number I was looking for, not 50. Thank you!

Comment: You couldn't theoretically use xlwt at all. It only writes .xls. You could theoretically use xlrd and XlsxWriter, as long as what you need to preserve can be read by (and is exposed by) xlrd. In your actual case (which involves more complex requirements), xlrd wouldn't be enough, so pywin32 is appropriate.